# How can i run my python model automatically after specific time interval?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, web, deployment

Hey everyone hope you all are fine ....
I want to ask something from you, recently I build my model (Random Forest) in python machine learning and I got my predictions and make a web app in django that shows predicted values in front end. Now I want to deploy my web app and wants that after specific time interval my data become downloaded from api automatically, similar for data training file and data prediction file. Each task should run automatically after specific time interval because now each time I run program separately for data downloading, data training and doing prediction on data I want all these task should run automatically after specific time interval how I will achieve this task.... ?

Comment: You might want to import threading and add a separate thread to your web application, where the second thread basically just sleeps for 24 hours and then calls your function that downloads the new data etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the server is not on Docker or Windows, use [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab).

I would recommend setting up the data jobs as management commands, and then using the crontab to trigger them at the desired interval or time of day.

**settings.py**

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('0   4 * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['download_the_data']),
]
```

Comment: If i implement all these mentioned steps and deploy on 0000webhost. Does it work ?

Comment: Does that hosting company allow django? Crontab requires at least a user account on a linux server. But this is easier than RQscheduler or running a Celery Beat service.

Comment: I am a window user but when i deploy my web app on heroku and add a cron job then it should work. isn't it ?

Comment: Heroku has its own scheduler service https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler